# How to select html content including the selector element

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Please get me out of this doubt.
My HTML code is

```
<div id="ToBe"><div class="text">Hello</div></div>
```

My jQuery code is

```
var x=$('#ToBe').html();
alert(x);
```

But it is displaying

```
<div class="text">Hello</div>
```

But my requirement is to display

```
"<div id="ToBe"><div class="text">Hello</div></div>"
```

as output.
How can i get that.

Comment: Sorry i did not see that. :-(

Comment: @Prathap: that’s alright — it’s good to have the question in Stack Overflow with your wording, because then people asking it in the future have a better chance of finding the existing answer.

Comment: @Ben: well-spotted. If you could vote to close this question as a duplicate of the one you linked to, future searchers will get redirected to the existing answer.

Comment: @Paul You are so right and kind. :)

Comment: @Sangdol: aw! Cheers! I’m actually a phenomenal bastard, but I do like having answers to every possible phrasing of every possible coding question ready in Stack Overflow for when I need to look it up :)